# "BBImage" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject in ios9

Tags: ios, core-data, ios-9-beta3

When I use coredata in my project everything is ok before ios9.
the code is like this

```
@interface BBImage : NSManagedObject

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * create_date;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * data_path;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * height;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * key;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * width;

@end
```

but when i run it in ios9 , i get an error :"BBImage" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.
I didnot know what should i do to reslove it.
I've used previous versions of the class name, if I change the class name version of the data will be lost before.

Comment: Since that snippet clearly shows that `BBImage` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, you need to edit your question to add more detail. What, exactly, is your code doing when that message appears?

Answer (score 0):

Another class BBText can work on ios9,ios8,ios7,ios6

```
    @interface BBText : NSManagedObject
            @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * create_date;
            @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * font;
            @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * fontsize;
            @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * modify_date;
            @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;
            @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text_color;
    @end
```